# How To Make A Song With Lyrics

Tags: video-editor, blender, openshot, lyrics

Today I was trying to make a video using song lyrics but I couldn't find a way, I want to add some effects for text(Animation) and Slide(Animation) I know many programs Windows relative but I don't have windows, I'm pure GNU/Linux user, I want to know is there any method to do that under Open Source Software, any help appreciate!

Here is example of what I'm trying to do

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YYg0uPyTbM

Comment: You need a text to speech converter? See no 14 [here](http://www.allfreeubuntu.tk/advanced-apps/)

Comment: No, I need to create a video using photos with animation text (text = song lyrics)

Comment: The video you provided in the link is removed.

Answer (score 3):

**Synfig Studio**

You can use Synfig Studio to make the text animation video.

```
sudo apt-get install synfig
```

[image: Install via the software center]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your interested in blender you can do all the animation there. An addon that can help with animated text effects is https://github.com/BenSimonds/Randomiser

There is a [short example video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg93ksWYKws) and a [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ys7Rh76jUN8)

The addon is animating the content of a text object, so you can give it thickness and move it around the screen as it being written out.

If you need help with blender, it has it's own [stackexchange site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is why I love stackexchange. You just given a complete package to the OP (software, how to use, where to check incase of any issues. +1